# $f:P(N) \rightarrow P(N)$ is defined by $f(x) = X \Delta D$ prove $Img(f) = P(N)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

let $D$ be a set of  the primes 
and $f:P(N) \rightarrow P(N)$ is defined by $f(x) = X \Delta D$

i need to prove $Img(f) = P(N)$ but i dont know how to start.. 
i thought  $f(x) = X \Delta D$ means that every x i choose must be prime but im not sure that is true

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad is it better?